# Django multiple form factory

Tags: python, django, django-forms

What is the best way to deal with multiple forms? I want to combine several forms into one. For example, I want to combine ImangeFormSet and EntryForm into one form:

```
class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
ImageFormSet = formset_factory(ImageForm)

class EntryForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

result_form = combine(EntryForm, ImageFormSet) # here it goes
```

I found 2 years old presentation introducing multipleform_factory() method, but I am not sure that it's the best way: http://www.slideshare.net/kingkilr/forms-getting-your-moneys-worth

Comment: Why do they need to be combined?

Comment: I can process each form separately, but it seems to be easier to work with one form instead of two, three... There are some points at presentation (it is really short and I can't say better).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea (not checked if it works):

```
class MySuperForm(CombinedForm):
    includes = (ImageForm, EntryForm, )
```

You [see here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L380) how the form is built. You can make your own Form by extending from BaseForm and supplying another `__metaclass__`.

```
class CombinedForm(BaseForm):
  __metaclass__ = DeclarativeFieldsMetaclassFromMultipleClasses
```

In DeclarativeFieldsMetaclassFromMultipleClasses you do basically the same as [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L54), except you sum up the declared fields from the classes on

```
class DeclarativeFieldsMetaclassFromMultipleClasses(type):
  def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
    for clazz in attrs['includes']:
      attrs['base_fields'] += get_declared_fields(bases, clazz.attrs)
    new_class = super(DeclarativeFieldsMetaclassFromMultipleClasses,cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
    if 'media' not in attrs:
      new_class.media = media_property(new_class)
    return new_class
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter how many forms are placed in template, because individual forms don't render form tag. So, your template goes like this

```
<form id='xxxx' action='' method=POST>  
  {{my_first_formset}}  
  {{my_second_form}}  
</form>
```

and in view.py

```
my_formset = MyFormset(request.POST)  
my_form = MyForm(request.POST)  
if my_formset.is_valid() and my_form.is_valid():  
   process...
```